# If range contains errors, clear errors VBA

Tags: vba

New to VBA and stackoverflow.

I want to search a worksheet and if there are errors (#N/A etc.) I would like to clear them. If there are no errors do nothing.

I used:

```
Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas,xlErrors).Clear
```

which worked fine when there are errors but if there are no errors I end up in debug mode.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add

```
 On Error Resume Next
```

to your VBA method that contains your SpecialCells Clear().

This is needed because when the `SpecialCells` Method condition cannot be met, an error occurs!

Comment: Thanks! Those are both great solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mitch answer which will fix your issue, its better to define a range variable and test if its not nothing and then clear it. See below code.

```
Sub sample()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Clear
    End If

End Sub
```